# How to put a handler inside onPostExecute to send a http request every 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest

I have to get new value from the server every 5 seconds. How to put handler right in onPostExecute

Required code looks like:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            requestHttp();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

But i want exact code to execute doInBackground and onPostExecute and so on...

Comment: `onPostExecute` is a callback of `AsyncTask`, which I think has already been deprecated. Other than that, you should really think twice before doing a poll like that.

Comment: Please help me how do I get the updated value from the server then?

Comment: I have added the code as i found it somewhere on stackoverflow. But it says Cannot resolve method 'requestHttp()';

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems like you really need to start from the beginning. Find a guide a start reading it. You can find tons of information here: https://developer.android.com/guide

Comment: Yeah I am a beginner, how to send httprequest every 5 seconds using handler in onPostExecute, simple way. please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617621/android-how-to-send-http-request-via-service-every-10-seconds

Comment: Handler will execute on the thread where it is created, so if you are executing it in `onPostExecute` which itself invoked in the UI thread you will end up making a network call in the UI thread which will crash the app anyway.